# North Star and Fist of Suns

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A [discussion on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/magicTCG/comments/1hlbp9/little_does_m14_know_its_substantially_buffing_my/cavg88c) about bad combos mentioned combining the following two cards (Oracle included here):

[Fist of Suns](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fist%20of%20Suns)

> You may pay {W}{U}{B}{R}{G} rather than pay the mana cost for spells that you cast.

[North Star](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=North%20Star)

> {4}, {T}: For one spell this turn, you may spend mana as though it were mana of any color to pay that spell's mana cost. (Additional costs are still paid normally.)

The idea being that by activating North Star you could pay {5} to play anything instead of the usual {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}, due to the oracle wording. The total mana cost would be 9 mana thanks to the {4} required to activate North Star of course.

Does this combo work?

Comment: Without looking at the Reddit thread, I am almost certain the entire reason for posting the combo was to make a "Fist of the North Star" joke.

Comment: You could do a Celestial Dawn / Fist of the Suns to make all spells cost WWWWW though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe it works due to the wording of the rules regarding costs.

> 202.1. A card’s mana cost is indicated by mana symbols near the top of the card. (See rule 107.4.)
>
> 601.2e The player determines the total cost of the spell. Usually this is just the mana cost. Some
> spells have additional or alternative costs.

Fist of Suns has a static ability that creates an alternative cost for all spells that are played. This alternative cost if {W}{U}{B}{R}{G}. However that alternative cost is not the mana cost which is still the original printed symbols.

For this reason when both are out if you attempt to pay the alternative cost of {W}{U}{B}{R}{G} you are no longer paying the mana cost, so the ability to pay mana as if it were mana of any color no longer applies.

Thus after activating North Star with Fist of Suns in play you can either pay {W}{U}{B}{R}{G} or the CMC of the spell, but cannot choose to pay {5}.

Comment: This is correct. It does not work as NS doesn't affect the alternative cost created by FoS.